# remove \n from the end of list item

Tags: python

I have this code

```
def return_not_existing_signals(list_of_signals,read_or_write) :
    not_used_produced_signals = []
    #print(list_of_signals)
    if read_or_write =="read":
        file_to_create= "c:\\path\\read.txt"
    else:
        file_to_create = "c:\\path\\write.txt"

    for i in list_of_signals :
        i.replace('\n','')
        if not search_for_signals(i) :
            not_used_produced_signals.append(i)
    write_to_txt(not_used_produced_signals,file_to_create)


def search_for_signals(name_of_signal):
    for filename in Path('c:\path').glob('**/*.h') : 
        with open(filename) as f:
            if name_of_signal in f.read():
                return True
    return False
```

The problem is that some of the `list_of_signals` are having \n at the end ( example: test1234rwq4\n)

`I.replace(\'n',' ' )` isn't working

Comment: `i.rstrip()` might work for you.

Comment: Or, `i.replace('\n', '')`.

Comment: You need to assign it like `i = i.replace('\n','')`

Comment: @NishantNawarkhede Oh i feel so dumb now :P If you could please put it as an answer so i can accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [***docs***](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace):

> **string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace])**
>
> ***Return a copy of string s***
> ***with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new***. If the optional
> argument maxreplace is given, the first maxreplace occurrences are
> replaced.

Hence you need to to it as,

```
i = i.replace('\n','')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
strg = "Helllo\nwhatsup?"
New_strg = strg.replace('\n','')
print(New_strg)
```

Output:

> Hellowhatsup?